# REGEX - negar preposições em nome de logradouros

Tags: regex, exceção

Estou precisando de ajuda em uma regex. Preciso fazer batimento de logradouros na base dos Correios, mas por causa das preposições muitos logradouros não são encontrados.

Exemplo:

Arquivo de entrada = RUA PRAIA **DA** ARMACAO

Base dos Correios = RUA PRAIA **DE** ARMACAO

Arquivo de saída = **Logradouro não encontrado**

Preciso de uma regex que ignore as preposições e procure tudo que estiver antes e depois dela.

Consegui chegar na expressão que me retorna as preposições (\sDE\s|\sDA\s|\sDO\s).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando coloco a negação (?!\sDE\s|\sDA\s|\sDO\s), não retorna nada.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não precisar ser nada para uma linguagem específica, funcionando em editor de texto já está Ok para o que eu preciso. A busca do logradouro será feita por StringReplacer do FME (imagem abaixo).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual linguagem você está utilizando? poste seu código relevante

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não é para nenhuma linguagem específica. Funcionando no editor de texto já está Ok para o que eu preciso. A busca será feita no FME utilizando StringReplacer.

Comment: Dizer qual _engine_ de expressão regular é importante. Se não o fizer, quem responder poderá dar uma resposta válida para `sed` mas que não seja válida em, sei lá, `PCRE`. Ou que seja `PCRE` mas não reconhecida pelo Eclipse. (PS: foram exemplos, não sei da compatibilidade do `sed` com `PCRE` nem com Eclipse/regex Java)

Comment: Favor colocar a lista dos logradouros em uma tabela de texto. Pode usar este [site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Answer (score 1):

Existe um Transformer no FME chamado FuzzyStringComparer ou FuzzyStringCompareFrom2Datasets.

Esse transformador calcula um índice de similaridade para dois atributos.
Estes atributos podem estar ou não no mesmo dataset. Depois de calculado esse grau de similaridade você consegue realizar um filtro de corte para pegar apenas os registros que retornaram uma similaridade alta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Admitindo que cada morada só tem uma preposição e só procuramos as preposições "DE", "DA" e "DO", podemos simplificar as comparações usando a expressão:

```
 /^(.*?)((?:\sD[AEO])(\s.*))?$/
```

A consequência é que a existir uma proposição, ao capturarmos as partes relevantes - grupo 1 e grupo 3 (se esta existir), não ficariam no mesmo grupo mas se, em código, for criada uma nova string como a concatenação dos dois grupos, a comparação pode ser feita.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas não funcionou... coloquei a regex no fluxo mas não encontrou nada, nem no FME nem no editor de texto.